# Generic MDIO device tree node to access switch registers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

We are connected ethernet switch to SoC using MDIO and MDC lines. We need to add mdio entries in the device tree source for this switch. Can anyone guide me to the sample kernel source for this. There is no driver available for the switch. We need to access the switch registers through MDIO and MDC lines. Looking for a sample MDIO device tree node in this scenario.

Most of the MDIO entries are linked with PHY drivers. Looking for a sample generic standalone MDIO device tree node.

Comment: "*There is no driver available for the switch. We need to access the switch registers through MDIO and MDC lines.*" - That seem like a contradiction. The purpose of a Device Tree is to describe the hardware to the kernel, i.e. provide information to configure device drivers. If there's "*no driver*:, then why do you need a DT node? If you had a driver, then that driver specifies what has to be in its node (using a 'bindings' document). Maybe writing a device driver is in your future?

Comment: Driver is not available from Marvell for this switch. Using MDIO and MDC lines I need to update the registers of the switch. Maybe you are correct I need to write a MDIO driver. Any small MDIO driver in the kernel source, which I can refer for writing MDIO for my requirement?